# Error with including ffmpeg to a project

Tags: linux, eclipse, compilation, linker, ffmpeg

I have faced problem with compilation project including ffmpeg library and I have no idea what to do with that error.

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libavformat.a(utils.o): undefined reference to symbol 'av_reduce@@LIBAVUTIL_51' ffmpeg          C/C++ Problem
```

and here is my linker

```
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -o "ffmpeg"  ./ffmpeg.o   -lpthread -lswscale -lavdevice -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lavfilter -lm -lz -lmp3lame -lpostproc -ldl -lX11 -lSDL -lrt -lswresample
```

If someone could help me t will be great.
Thx

Comment: this is with standard ffmpeg configure && make?

Comment: once I followd this:  [ http://wiki.razuna.com/display/ecp/FFmpeg+Installation+for+Ubuntu#FFmpegInstallationforUbuntu-InstallFFmpegonUbuntu] and the second one by ffmpeg tutorial and got the same error.

Comment: so you're installing it onto 32 bit ubuntu? what's your full ouput for just using configure && make ?

Comment: 32 bit lubuntu. Hmm, Right now I dont have one because configure and make run without error, should I look there for something ?

Comment: if they run without error, what are you attempting to do with the above error message?

Comment: make while build didn't call any error. But when I try to compile project with ffmpeg libs I got this error. ITs an output from compiling  project that include libs build before.

Comment: hmm...kind of confused me that your linker was trying to create a file called "ffmpeg" anyway, I'd suggest looking carefully at how ffmpeg's own configure/make is able to create a working ffmpeg, and try and duplicate that.  Also make sure you ran a make install [I presume you did]

Comment: ;) Thats the problem that  I did it 3 times - even 2 times on fresh linux. I cannot move on.

Comment: possibly you have some other "libavformat.a" files on your system?

Comment: right now I am trying one more time on fresh linux. I see i have at    /usr/lib/i386... one libavformat.a, one libavutil.a and some libavutil.so so.51 so.51.22.2

Comment: Can I use .so libs instead of .a  ? and How it differ between .so .so.51?

Comment: yeah the multiple libavutil.so versions may be a problem... (I think it automatically uses and links against what it finds, .so first)

Comment: SO Can You recomend sth? Should I remove some .so ? and let only version that match trought all libs ?  I mean : only .so.51 if there are in other libs like avdevice etc?

Comment: yeah probably remove them all, install again [make sure only one version appears listed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  this :
[Error with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582298/error-with-ffmpeg-undefined-whole)

Also use:

```
ld --verbose -l * where * is lib that u're looking for
```

and ensure that your linker found library that you expect( path to your compiled libs).